# Barcode and QR code Scanner in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

Can anyone help me on my way to add a bar/qr code scanner to my SAPUI5 application? I got told to add a kapsel plugin, but these aren't license free. Anything to help me get on my way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested in the upcoming native web API [BarcodeDetector](https://wicg.github.io/shape-detection-api/#barcode-detection-api). On Chrome, you can already try it out: Go to *chrome://flags*,  turn this flag on: `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`, and visit https://qrsnapper.appspot.com/ | [GitHub](https://github.com/PaulKinlan/qrcode) (a small [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) which works also offline and replaced my native QR scanner on Android).

Comment: The [mentioned demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768716/barcode-and-qr-code-scanner-in-sapui5#comment86568202_49768716) also uses the lib [jsqrcode](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode) as a fallback implementation if it couldn't detect the BarcodeDetector API support.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used a Cordova shell for the fiori application because it doesn't have to be deployed to SCP.